# Can I make Notepad++ or another source code editor do more syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax, editor, syntax-highlighting

I'm not a very experienced programmer and I have very limited experience with source code editors. Currently, I am using Notepad++ and pretty happy with it.

But I've always wanted it to be a bit more graphic so that I can more easily read through the code and see what is going on where.

One thing I'd like to have is the possibility to use colors and font sizes in my comments, sort of like I would use headings in websites or in a book. By that I mean actual font sizes that are visible to the programmer in the editor itself.

Another thing that I would love to have is the possibility to have background colors for if statements, for loops, etc.

Example: If statements could be shades of blue, getting darker when they are nested, for loops could be shades of red, etc.

Like this but with a better color palette: https://jsfiddle.net/y5Lv889c/2/

```
<h1 style="font-size: 20px; color: red">My colorful heading in a large font</h1>
<div style="background-color: blue;">
  if ($this) {  
  <div style="background-color: #4F37CC;margin: 10px;">
      if ($that) { 
        <div style="background-color: red; margin:10px">
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { <br>
          doThis($i);<br>
        } <br>
        </div>
<div style="background-color: red; margin:10px">
        for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) { <br>
          doThat($i);<br>
        } <br>
        </div>
    }  
</div>
```

Is there something like this available for Notepad++ or another editor?

Comment: why not use a dedicated code editor / IDE ? VS Code is free and multi platform and has syntax highlighting for many languages, as an example.

Comment: You can't ask us to recommend or find an editor here. See the [help/on-topic], specifically item #4 in the section with the numbered list on that page. There is no generic, one-size-fits-all answer to the question you've asked, either.

Comment: Suggested good, Notepad++-like code editors: [Emacs](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/download.html), [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/3).

Comment: @AndrewP I would if it could do what I asked about. But it doesn't look like it from what I can see without downloading it.

Comment: @KenWhite I didn't know about that. Although I would say that there could be a "one size fits all" answer to my question if I changed it so that it would be asking for a Notepad++ plugin and not other editors. Which is what I meant to do, I just included the "another editor" part because it seems a lot of questions related to Notepad++ end up with people recommending another editor. But I think Notepad++ is great... maybe that's because the only other editors I have used are Notepad and Dreamweaver.

Comment: @jmoon But can they do what I was asking about? Don't want to switch from Notepad++ if they can't do that.

Comment: *One size fits all* means *one solution that can be applied globally*. Your question asked for a global solution. Clearly if you (properly) edited your question to make it specific to NP++, my comment would not have been made. My comment was meant to point out your question was **not specific** (*Notepad++ or another editor*), as well as being a tool recommendation question (which remains off-topic).

Comment: @Andri formatting within comments- no, but syntax highlighting for other things, e.g. `Another thing that I would love to have is the possibility to have background colors for if statements, for loops, etc.`, yes.

Comment: @KenWhite Yes, you are right. Sorry about that.

Comment: @AndrewP Oh, great. Thanks, I'll try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use [VS Community](https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/community/?rr=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com.br%2F) version for tests

[image]

Comment: Can it do what I asked about?

Comment: Yeah, you can do lot customizations highlighting, check: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/themes-snippets-colorizers

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it out